# Set default browser when running as sudo

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, default-browser

I am trying to run sudo and set the default browser. I want to set chromium as my default browser. I have tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

This shows chrome as my default browser. However when I run in sudo mode and try to use grunt , it keeps using firefox as the default browser. Without sudo it goes back to google chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections
```

[image]

Find out what is set as the `x-www-browser`, it will probably be Firefox, then do this:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser
```

[image]

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/chromium-browser /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser
```

[image]